# Asking for help with work - manager/ supervisor doesn't seem interested

Tags: manager, work-experience, training, helping

#### Some background

I'm a junior/ graduate developer (trained in JS, C++ & Swift while at university) working in a SAP development role. This is my first graduate job, although I have worked for a year in industry at a very reputable software development company (a role which was nothing to do with SAP, and more tailored to my university degree) as part of my placement, prior to the completion of my university degree.

My day to day responsibilities at my current role vary, as I am often assigned projects completely outside of my field of expertise/ training (tasks which include, but are not limited to, creating Power BI reports, analysing finance data and creating dashboards).

I've been at the company for 1 year, have never used SAP or ABAP before and have never received any formal training with the SAP ecosystem since starting at this company. My now manager sat with me for the first week of work to go through the basics of ABAP programming and how to create reports, smartforms etc. but nothing outside of programming. For those not familiar, SAP has quite the learning curve.

#### Problem

Since my first real assignment at this role, I've been consistently given the so called, "*shit jobs*" - jobs which my supervisor/ mentor and now manager didn't and still doesn't want to do; such as: refactoring code left by incompetent contractors, dealing with the creation of Power BI dashboards for the business and sometimes completely redeveloping entire programs/ workflows. Needless to say I have been given a lot of responsibility for someone who does not know anything about the SAP environment.

Recently I received a task to create an 'ABAP query' (for those familiar with SAP, SQ01) to display some data from our SAP system in a graphical format.

I was advised by my manager that I can create this query directly in the live/ production environment. Having never done this in my entire time working here, I was a little hesitant in proceeding to complete the task on my own. Regardless, I took initiative, did some research online and attempted to begin.

Ultimately not making any progress on my own, I began to asked my manager for help with the task.

I asked multiple times (and I mean at least 10-15 times overall) to advise me on how to proceed at every hurdle I faced but he would only come over for about 20 seconds then leave again, getting visibly frustrated with my incompetence with the system, muttering swears and all sorts under his breath. Leaving me with more questions and needing guidance on how to proceed.

This has happened a lot before when dealing with the refactoring tasks and various other bits and pieces.

#### Question

I have asked for formal training before but since my role is primarily for software development, other aspects of SAP fall slightly out of scope and my manager always keeps me busy with something critical, preventing me from having free time for training.

Is there any other way for me to ask for help with something I am not familiar/ comfortable with in doing on my own?

His behaviour and responses (or lack thereof) lead me to feel like I am being a nuisance asking for help with work - which is extremely demoralising and makes me feel worthless in my responsibilities. 



Additionally, I recently (3 days prior to posting this question) handed in my resignation letter (for somewhat obvious reasons) and will be leaving the role in a month's time. Which I admit, does not help the situation at all. But should this situation happen again in the future, I wish to know how to deal with it appropriately.

It's also worth mentioning that there are currently 3 developers in the team I work in; including myself, my manager and one contractor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather large and complex problem because there may (or may not) be different options that work in different situations - so, it's a little hard to be specific about how you should handle this *in the future* versus in a specific context. But, that said, you should take some comfort in the fact that you're not alone in this struggle. Many people fresh out of school and new to the professional workforce struggle with similar issues.

That said, here are some ideas:

First, **Start by finding a job where you can be happy and effective.** Not all "developer" roles are the same. As you've discovered, being part of a small team of developers embedded in a large organization that has a non-software focus can often mean that you're asked to wear many different hats, you're expected to be able to learn the industry (or already know it), and you will regularly be working with people who don't understand things that seem obvious to you (such as, the difference between a developer trained in C++ versus someone trained to build PowerBI reports. Or why it's a bad idea for a newbie to write queries in PROD).

On the other hand, a company with a larger, more highly structure software team, or even an employer who's actual end product *is* software, will likely have more segmentation among roles (along with the ability to hire appropriately for those roles), less dependency on developers understanding business nuance, and less chance for you to be left all on your own (since you'll have more peers to learn from).

So, rather than just look for a job, or spamming every opening you can find, **focus on finding the right job.** Don't be afraid to turn down offers or walk away from opportunities that would result in you finding yourself right back in this same position again. Otherwise, you might as well just rescind your resignation and stay where you are! Do the following:

- Reflect on what will make you successful in a job. Write your own "reverse job description" that describes the environment you're looking for. This may feel silly, but it'll help you focus your thoughts and should not be overlooked.
- Read job postings carefully and look for indicators that will tell you about the environment you'll be working in.
- Try to determine the age and "maturity" of the team you'll be joining
- Come up with a list of questions to ask the hiring manager in the interview, so you can be informed about the type of work you'll be doing, the support you'll get, and how issues will be handled.

Secondly, **Learn to help yourself.** You may already be an expert at this, but it's not apparent from the way you've written this question. In fact, it seems like perhaps the opposite is true: you mentioned asking your boss for help on the same thing 10 or 15 times. With all due respect, that strikes me as a sign that *you're doing it wrong.* Of course, it's always appropriate to ask for help when you're stuck. But, you can always consider alternatives, which may be effective in certain environments:

- Use Google, Stack Exchange, or other online resources. Ask questions online. SAP does have a huge learning curve, but it also has a huge market share, which means there is an overwhelming amount of information about it online. You can find tutorials, walkthroughs, examples, user forums, support portals, and so on. There is even an [ABAP tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abap) on Stack Overflow.
- Look in your own environment for examples you can copy from. Even if you can't find something that does exactly what you need, you may be able to find boilerplate that gets you started. You were afraid of writing that query in prod, but maybe there were other queries in prod already that you could copy from.
- Look for internal documentation from past work. Even if the work is not relevant, you may be able to glean some context clues.
- Think back to your time at school, and what methods helped you learn. Lean on those. Maybe you learn best by watching tutorials on youtube, versus reading a book. Or something else. Your degree gave you software development skills, but more importantly, it (hopefully) taught you about how you, personally, are best able to learn. Graduating and getting a job doesn't mean you're done learning: you still need to be able to leverage your "I learned how to learn" skill.
- Ask your peers, instead of your boss. Even on small teams, there's usually someone around who has done this before, other than your boss.
- And of course, as a final resort, ask your boss.

Thirdly, and relevant to those last two suggestions, when you do find that you must ask for help, **make sure you ask for help in a way that will best let someone help you.** Instead of saying,

> I'm stuck

or

> I don't know how to do this

you want to prepare ahead of time so you can instead say,

> Hey boss, I'm trying to write that query you assigned to me, and I found this example I'm working from. I changed the filter on it but I'm getting less records than I expected. I checked with Chris and he said that it might be due to the way I'm joining to the Purchase Orders table, but he doesn't know anything about purchase orders. Can you let me know who I can talk to that might know enough about the purchase orders table to help me solve this?

The keys here are,

- You've done some research on your own, and tried out ideas you've found
- You've asked others who might know the answer
- You're asking a specific, answerable question (who knows about purchase orders) instead of just saying, "I have an obstacle" or "I'm stuck."

In summary, make sure you're setting yourself up for success in terms of how you pick your next job. Reflect on what makes you happy, and then look for that. Then, when the inevitable roadblocks do happen, make sure you're doing due diligence instead of running to your boss the minute you're stuck. Then, if or when you do need to ask for help, be sure to do it in a way that will actually let the other person help you.

Comment: I could not agree more with learn to help yourself.  There is no greater skill to have as a software developer then problem solving skills.  Your supervisor may be a lot like me and when I have an employee asking me a lot of questions instead of spending the time figuring it out I have to start questioning if software development is the right profession for them.